# Is this proof correct? (chernoff bound)

Tags: probability, inequality

In [Stanford cs 265](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs265/#classes) lecture5.

Following is the proof of the first statement of corollary6.

> [image]
> Where $X=X_1+\dots+X_n$, $X_i$ are independent 0/1 random variables.

**Theorem 2**

> [image]

We can see that the proof apply theorem 2 to $Z$.

My question:
I think $Z$ is not the sum of $0/1$ random variables So we can't apply Theorem2 to $Z$,  because $Z$ can be $2n$. So is this proof wrong?

Comment: The corollary is false in general since it would suggest that all random variables $X$ with a finite mean have $P[X>t]$ that decays exponentially with $t$. There must be some additional (hidden) assumptions on $X$ that would give meaning to this corollary.

Comment: @Michael X is the sum of independent 0/1 variables. Thanks for your remind, I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, after dicussing with my classmate, I found that $Z$ equals the sum of $2n$ 0/1 random variables, so we can apply **theorem2** to $Z$.